# Is there an ASP.NET word processing control?

Tags: asp.net, rich-text-editor, word-processor

Is there a full-blown ASP.NET word processing control? One that runs in every (main) browser, and includes support for page margins, page & section breaks, fields, etc?

TextControl has the functionality but only runs in IE. The editors from Telerik, DevExpress, etc are HTML editors - so no concept of margins, breaks, etc.

I don't care if it's paid or open source.

Comment: Open-ended recommendation type questions like this one are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. See the "not constructive" close reason in the [faq#close] - I think this doesn't really require specific expertise, just happenstance knowledge of a control, or good Googling skills. Also, I think this really qualifies as "polling" (also from that faq section).

Comment: I'm hoping this is allowed because the question is not which is best, but does one even exist.